# Having a fragment activity in a fullscreen activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have a fullscreen activity with fragments showing 3 TextViews, which the user can swipe through. The problem is with the action bar, on the emulator it works fine and when clicking on the activity it shows the System UI but when using the device the System UI doesn't show when clicking.

With tempering with the SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE i noticed that the onFling method isn't being used at all, when i first only coded the fragments it used swipe by default but still the System UI didn't show when tap or click. So i thought by implementing the onFling method i could temper with the swipe.

The following is the code.

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnGestureListener {

 private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
 private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
 private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.pager);


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
            HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView
                                .animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });




    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.
    findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(
            mDelayHideTouchListener);
}



public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }


}


public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());

        textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
}








@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}


View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};

private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}


 @Override
 public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
 {
 try {
 if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
 return false;
 // right to left swipe
 if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 else if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swipe up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swipe down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 } catch (Exception e) {
 // nothing
 }

 return true;
 }


@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following way, In your onCreate() method add below line,

```
 this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

The above line must be after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` line

Like below,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ...
}
```